# How to use dcmtk/dcmprscp in Windows

Tags: dcmtk

How can I use dcmprscp to receive from SCU Printer a DICOM file and save it, I'm using dcmtk 3.6 & I've some trouble to use it with the default help, this's what I'm doing in CMD:

```
dcmprscp.exe --config dcmpstat.cfg --printer PRINT2FILE
```

each time I receive this messagebut (database\index.da) don't exsist in windows

```
W: $dcmtk: dcmprscp v3.6.0 2011-01-06 $
W: 2016-02-21 00:08:09
W: started
E: database\index.dat: No such file or directory
F: Unable to access database 'database'
```

I try to follow some tip, but the same result : 
http://www.programmershare.com/2468333/

http://www.programmershare.com/3020601/

and this's my printer's PRINT2FILE config :

```
[PRINT2FILE]
hostname = localhost
type = LOCALPRINTER
description = PRINT2FILE
port = 20006 
aetitle = PRINT2FILE 
DisableNewVRs = true 
FilmDestination = MAGAZINE\PROCESSOR\BIN_1\BIN_2 
SupportsPresentationLUT = true 
PresentationLUTinFilmSession = true 
PresentationLUTMatchRequired = true 
PresentationLUTPreferSCPRendering = false 
SupportsImageSize = true 
SmoothingType = 0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\10\11\12\13\14\15 
BorderDensity = BLACK\WHITE\150 
EmptyImageDensity = BLACK\WHITE\150 
MaxDensity = 320\310\300\290\280\270 
MinDensity = 20\25\30\35\40\45\50 
Annotation = 2\ANNOTATION 
Configuration_1 = PERCEPTION_LUT=OEM001 
Configuration_2 = PERCEPTION_LUT=KANAMORI 
Configuration_3 = ANNOTATION1=FILE1 
Configuration_4 = ANNOTATION1=PATID 
Configuration_5 = WINDOW_WIDTH=256\WINDOW_CENTER=128 
Supports12Bit = true 
SupportsDecimateCrop = false 
SupportsTrim = true 
DisplayFormat=1,1\2,1\1,2\2,2\3,2\2,3\3,3\4,3\5,3\3,4\4,4\5,4\6,4\3,5\4,5\5,5\6,5\4,6\5,6 
FilmSizeID = 8INX10IN\11INX14IN\14INX14IN\14INX17IN 
MediumType = PAPER\CLEAR FILM\BLUE FILM 
MagnificationType = REPLICATE\BILINEAR\CUBIC
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmprscp.html) of the "dcmprscp" tool says:

> The dcmprscp utility implements the DICOM Basic Grayscale Print
>   Management Service Class as SCP. It also supports the optional
>   Presentation LUT SOP Class. The utility is intended for use within the
>   DICOMscope viewer.

That means, it is usually not run from the command line (as most of the other DCMTK tools) but started automatically in the background by [DICOMscope](http://dicom.offis.de/dscope).

Anyway, I think the error message is clear:

```
E: database\index.dat: No such file or directory
F: Unable to access database 'database'
```

Did you check whether there is a subdirectory "database" and whether the "index.dat" file exists in this directory? If you should ask why there is a need for a "database" then please read the next paragraph of the documentation:

> The dcmprscp utility accepts print jobs from a remote Print SCU.
>   It does not create real hardcopies but stores print jobs in the local
>   DICOMscope database as a set of Stored Print objects (one per page)
>   and Hardcopy Grayscale images (one per film box N-SET)

Comment: Actually I need it in the command line, plus it doesn't support DICOM Basic Color, is there othere lib better then this one ?

Comment: Of course, you can use this tool from the command line but then you need to set up the configuration accordingly (config file and database directory). Anyway, it does not support Basic Color Print Management. There is a commercial extension from OFFIS, called DCMPRINT, that supports this and many other features.

Comment: Is there a trial version for this OFFIS-DCMPRINT ? and how I can buy it

Comment: Should be easy to find out (using your favorite search engine): http://dicom.offis.de/evaluation